# Understanding ARM64 Obj-C Prolog

Tags: disassembly, assembly, arm

I'm trying to understand the differences between the following function prologs of a number of obj-c function decompilations.

I know they store variables for the caller to use when the function returns. But why the differences?

Sample 1

```
void * -[Issue ideal](void * self, void * _cmd)
sub        sp, sp, #0x40
stp        x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
stp        x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
stp        x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
add        x29, sp, #0x30
mov        x19, x0
```

Sample 2

```
void * -[Issue path](void * self, void * _cmd)
stp        x26, x25, [sp, #-0x50]!
stp        x24, x23, [sp, #0x10]
stp        x22, x21, [sp, #0x20]
stp        x20, x19, [sp, #0x30]
stp        x29, x30, [sp, #0x40]
add        x29, sp, #0x40
mov        x19, x0
```

Sample 3

```
void -[ContentView showPageThumb:page:data:guid:](void * self, void * _cmd, void * arg2, long long arg3, void * arg4, void * arg5)
stp        x24, x23, [sp, #-0x40]!
stp        x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
stp        x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
stp        x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
add        x29, sp, #0x30
mov        x20, x5
mov        x21, x4
mov        x22, x3
mov        x19, x0
mov        x0, x2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touched this stuff for a while, but I'd say compiler is simply saving opcodes or following a complicated template, perhaps to do with optimisation. Notice that

```
stp        x24, x23, [sp, #-0x40]!
stp        x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
stp        x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
stp        x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
```

does the same job as

```
sub        sp, sp, #0x40
stp        x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
stp        x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
stp        x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
```

plus stores one additional register `x24` . This because the first example uses writeback addressing in `[sp, #-0x40]!`

http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/addressing.html (a random google result on addressing modes in ARM).

Same with your second example - it still allocates x50 bytes on the stack. The difference is rather superficial, they all do the same job. `add`,`mov`s are not part of prologue IIRC.